# Numerical constant in C++

Tags: c++, enums, embedded

I saw a lot of questions concerning what should be preferred between [static const vs #define vs enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum/).

In none of them was discussed the aspect of resources, which is important in embedded system.

I don't like to use `#define` but it doesn't consume resources like `static`. What about `enum`, does in consume RAM\ROM?

In addition, I was told that if i use e.g. `const int` it will not consume either RAM nor ROM, assuming I do not use pointer\reference to this variable.
Is this true?

If this is true, wouldn't it be a good solution to use `const int` inside a `namespace` in order to save resources?

**Remark**: I am using C++ 2003 standard and can't use 2011 standard. (I already saw `enum class` and constexpr in 2011, but i can't use them.)

Comment: Did you see ["static const" vs "#define" vs "enum"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum/) — though that's tagged C rather than C++?  `enum` uses no more resource than `#define` (except in the debug information).  The compiler will probably use minimal resources whichever way you go — they're good at optimizing.

Comment: The aspects are already handled in the duplicate.

Comment: For c++11, it is more `constexpr` which is useful than `enum class` in this regard.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the aspect of using const in a namespace was not, since the tag was _C_

Comment: @Eagle You can always improve your question to get it reopened.

Comment: The difference between in a namespace and not, is pretty minimal.

Comment: You are wasting your time and energy worrying about a few words of memory.  Just write clean code that is easy to understand, debug and maintain.  Use whichever type of constant that provides the most understanding, or is easiest to debug or maintain.  Let the compiler manage the bytes (it's better at it than we are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... if i use e.g. `const int` it will not consume either RAM nor ROM, **assuming I do not use pointer\reference** to this variable

Exactly. If you use `#define` or `enum`, the compiler has no reason to put your constant in data memory - it will always put it in your code. If you use `const int`, the compiler will do the same only (mostly?) if your code has no references to it (i.e. when it's not ODR-used).

There are benign-looking constructs that silently introduce references into your code, so in practice you cannot assume `const int` will behave the same way as `enum`. For example:

```
const int UNIVERSE = 42;
int calc = ...;
int answer = max(calc, UNIVERSE);
```

If you use `max` from the `std` namespace (like you should), it will introduce a `const` reference to `UNIVERSE` to your code, which *may* add 42 to your data ROM.

Also:

```
bool condition = ...;
int answer = condition ? 0 : UNIVERSE;
```

The same problem here (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4209433/509868) for details); your code *may* behave differently with `const int` than either of `#define` or `enum`.

C++11 introduced `constexpr`, which will avoid these subtle problems. So if you cannot use C++11 and want maximum performance (or minimum memory wasted), you should use `#define` or `enum`. Also, if you want your constants to have type other than `int`, you're stuck with `#define`:

```
#define UNIVERSE (uint64_t)42
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions make no sense. All data has to be stored somewhere. You cannot store data in thin air.

The difference between `#define` and `const` is that the former tends to embed the constants with the code memory, while the latter may possibly give the variable a dedicated address in data memory. In either case, they will consume the same amount of memory.

If you don't enable any compiler optimizations, it is however possible that variables stored at dedicated address in data memory will result in a ever so slight change in memory consumption, it the case where the instruction fetching that data could as well have contained the raw value.

But these kind of micro-optimizations is not something you should even consider. We are talking about ROM memory, which you should have plenty of.

The advantage of such constants allocated at a fixed address, is that you can take their address and also view their values in a debugger. So they aren't necessarily the same thing as `#defined` ones.

Variables that are not used by your program will get optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a type does not, by itself, consume memory (ROM); except for debug information (if present).

So, simply;

```
enum MyValues {
  Value1,
  Value2
};
```

Will not consume ROM. However, instantiations of the type (actual objects) will consume memory (loaded from ROM and then later in RAM).

```
MyValues val1 = Value1;
```

Above, `val1` consume memory.

*So what is the difference to the `#define` or `const int` alternatives?*

Clarity.

The preprocessor (with the `#define`) and the compiler (with the `const int`) are smart enough to do pretty much exactly the same thing in most cases (outside of things such as taking the address of the `const int`). The `enum` is language construct that groups related values together, it's not the only one, but it is a very natural one.