# static int array in a class problem

Tags: c++, arrays, static

The following 3 code blocks are the main.cpp, static_class_array.cpp, and static_class_array.h respectively. I'm getting the following error:

```
static_class_array.cpp||In constructor 'static_array_class::static_array_class()':|
static_class_array.cpp|5|error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'int' in assignment|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

```
#include "static_class_array.h"

int main()
{
    static_array_class* array_class;

    array_class = new static_array_class();

    delete array_class;

    return 0;
}


#include "static_class_array.h"

static_array_class::static_array_class()
{
    static_array_class::array[3] = {0,1,2};
}
static_array_class::~static_array_class(){}



#ifndef STATIC_CLASS_ARRAY_H
#define STATIC_CLASS_ARRAY_H

class static_array_class
{
    private:

        static int array[3];

    public:

    static_array_class();
    ~static_array_class();
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you want in the implementation file is:

```
    static_array_class::static_array_class()
    {
    }
    static_array_class::~static_array_class(){}

    int static_array_class::array[3] = {0,1,2};
```

Explanation of error message

> "cannot convert 'brace-enclosed initializer list' to 'int' in
>   assignment"

in submitted code.

This is because the code:

```
static_array_class::array[3] = {0,1,2};
```

is interpreted as meaning that `{0,1,2}` should be assigned to element `3` in the array. Element `3` is of type `int`, (and incidentally not allocated being the fourth element), so this is like:

```
int i = 0;
i = {0,1,2};
```

Hence the error message.

Comment: told me I had a conflicting declaration.

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same type;

Your class is a class which includes a an array -- they other is just an array.

With a static definition of a class member you need to declare the actual instance outside the class, just like with any other static,

```
int static_array_class::array[3] = {0,1,2}; // note this line is outside the constructor

static_array_class::static_array_class()
{
}
static_array_class::~static_array_class(){}
```

Comment: Sure is possible with coding -- you just need a bit more -- static members of a class are initialized not in the constrictor but outside the class, since they are not actually part-taking in the constrction/deconstrction -- just can almost consider them just a part of the name space rather than the class.

Comment: Also see this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members

Comment: I tried that and then it tells me                                      \static_class_array\static_class_array.cpp|6|undefined reference to `static_array_class::array'|

Comment: Updated the answer, you need to move the initialization outside the constructor and declare the actual static member instance