# static member variable when declared private

Tags: c++, static-members

When a static member variable is declared private in a class, how can it be defined?

Suppose i have the following class declaration

```
class static_demo
{
   private:
      static int a;

   public:
      static int b;

      void set(int x, int y)
      {
         a = x;
         b = y;
      }

      void show()
      {
         cout << "a = " << a << "\n";
         cout << "b = " << b << "\n";
      }
};
```

Then the following statement to define `a` will result in compilation error.

```
int static_demo::a;
```

So is it possible to have a static data member in the private section of class?

**Adding full code as per Greg**,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class static_demo
{
   private:
      static int a;

   public:
      static int b;

      void set(int x, int y)
      {
         a = x;
         b = y;
      }
};

int static_demo::a;
int static_demo::b;

int main()
{
   static_demo::b = 10;
   static_demo::a = 20;

   return 0;
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
static_member_variable.cpp: In function `int main()':
static_member_variable.cpp:20: error: `int static_demo::a' is private
static_member_variable.cpp:26: error: within this context
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize private static members in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> When a static member variable is declared private in a class, how can it be defined?

In the very same way as you define a public static variable in your source(cpp) file.

> int static_demo::a = 1;

Access specifiers will not give you error while defining the member. Access specifiers control the access of the member variables, defining a static variable is an excpetion which is allowed.

Compiles cleanly on Ideone **[here](http://www.ideone.com/clone/ze2Zy)**.

**EDIT:** To answer your Q after you posted code.
Your problem is not the definition of the static member. The error is because you are trying to access the private static member inside `main`. You cannot do that.

Private members of a class can only be accessed inside the class member functions, the same rule applies even to static members. To be able to modify/access your static members you will have to add a member function to your class and then modify/access the static member inside it.

Comment: It’s not exactly an exception: it’s a definition of *a* member of the class, so it has access to *all* members of that class (including the one being defined), just as much as in the body of a member function defined outside the class.  Note that its type can be named using a private member even though it comes before the declarator entirely.

Answer (score 3):

in your .cpp:

```
int static_demo::a(0);
```

when this causes an error, it is most common that you either encountered a linker error for a multiply defined symbol (e.g. the definition was in the header), or that you may have tried to define it in the wrong scope. that is, if `static_demo` is in the `namespace MON`, it would be defined in the .cpp:

```
#include "static_demo.hpp"
int MON::static_demo::a(0);
```

for other types, it may simply have been an incorrect constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the definition, but the fact that in main() (that's not in the name scope of static_demo, and cannot see `a` being private), you do an **assignment**.

The definition of `a` is what you did at global scope, with `int static_demo::a;`.
You simply need an initializer, if you want `a` not to start with an undefined value.

```
int static_demo::a = 1;
```

will solve the problem.

From than on, `a` can be manipulated only by functions in `static_demo` (of friend of it).

Comment: `From than on, a can be manipulated only by static functions in static_demo (of friend of it).` is not correct.static members can also be accessed in non static member functions.check the [demo](http://www.ideone.com/SMyVt).