# Is it bad to not define a static array size in a class?--but rather to let it autosize

Tags: c++, arrays, class, static, static-members

Ex:
Is this acceptable? It compiles and seems to work for me; so is this bad form?

.h file

```
class MyClass
{
  static char c[];
};
```

.cpp file

```
char MyClass::c[] = "abcde";
```

---

Or must I do this instead, for example?

.h file

```
class MyClass
{
  static char c[10];
};
```

.cpp file

```
char MyClass::c[10] = "abcde";
```

Is there a benefit to one technique over the other? I'm not sure if I'm missing something. I don't know what I don't know, ya know?

### Update:

The original code I posted looked like this below. I edited it to make it as shown above since I didn't mean for the "private" aspect of it to be the point of discussion. In my real code (running on an Arduino), I am using .h and .cpp files and the static member is only intended to be accessed by the class. <s>**I guess I'm learning something new though too, as the answers regarding the below code seem to tell me that private static members are the same as public static members ie: they can both be modified by anything outside the class if static. That, I didn't know.**</s> WRONG, see the [answer by Alok Save here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857989/static-member-variable-when-declared-private). More on static member variables [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/). This line was especially helpful to me: *"Because static member variables are not part of the individual objects, you must explicitly define the static member if you want to initialize it to a non-zero value...This initializer should be placed in the code file for the class (eg. Something.cpp). In the absense of an initializing line, C++ will initialize the value to 0."*

```
class MyClass
{
  private:
  static char c[];
};

char MyClass::c[] = "abcde";
```

---

Or must I do this instead, for example?

```
class MyClass
{
  private:
  static char c[10];
};

char MyClass::c[10] = "abcde";
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `static char c[6]`? `char c[] = "abcde"` and `char c[10] = "abcde"` are not equivalent, because they create different sized arrays.

Comment: I think my confusion is where the memory is allocated when I don't specify the size. I'm afraid that if I do the first example with [], then the proper size won't be allocated and I'll be writing outside the array, since [] made the array size 0.  I've never created a char array string in two separate steps like this before without explicitly setting a size.

Comment: To answer you though, I don't know. `char c[] = "abcde"` will make c length 6 with null terminator at index 5. `char c[10] = "abcde"` will make c length 10, with null terminator at index 5. In either case I'm pretty sure the null terminator is there.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the part the null terminators. The memory should be allocated statically somewhere. The only difference (aside from the 6 vs 10) is that the compiler will take care of figuring out what to put between the square brackets if you give it a string literal.

Comment: Ok...things are clearing up, so *where* does the compiler set the size? It seems to me that when I say `static char c[];` all the compiler knows is that c is a pointer to a char, right? Then, when I do `char MyClass::c[] = "abcde";`, the compiler says, ok, I will allocate 6 bytes for you *and* set the c pointer to point to the start of the memory location where I just allocated 6 bytes, is that right?

Comment: Yes. It's equivalent to doing `class Foo { static char c[6]; };` and then later `char Foo:c[6] = "some string with 5 characters a null terminator";`

Comment: In other words, the first part creates a pointer called c, and the second part allocates memory for the char array (string) and does the equivalent of `c = char*-to-where-the-memory-was-just-allocated`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to be about whether to explicitly write the size of the array, rather than to deduce it from the assignment. Consider this:

What if you need to change the string value that the array is initialized to? If you explicitly define the size, you will need to change it in 3 places. First in the class definition, second in the static variable assignment. And third, you will also end up changing the value of the string assigned. *Not* explicitly writing the array size allows you to make the change in only one place. Additionally, it eliminates the possibility of forgetting to add 1 for the null terminator at the end of the string.

Clearly, this simplifies future code changes and does not sacrifice code clarity.

Comment: This is helping me; so, *not* explicitly setting the size makes the code more functional, while still allocating memory properly for the array?

Comment: Yes. Conceptually, the compiler will go through and add the appropriate array sizes in the code at compile time.

Comment: please see my answer to my own question, that I just posted to this question. Upvote it if it's correct. Comment if it's incorrect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Private variable should only access within ,it's class scope. when you ,put private without static ,it is safe and any one cannot access except with in class. in this case , I thin any one can change this variable , when creating a class.because this is static. he should ,only crate new class , and he know your variable name, he can change ,it value.

private variable should be private and that value should not access with out class method inside. please , visit OOP concept. you can get better idea. visit java access modifiers, you can take better idea.

you get take understand , why we put access modifiers.I think you , get some about your Question.

I think this is bad.

Comment: Sorry; bad example. In my real code I'm using a .h and .cpp file and this private variable is intended for use only within the class. The real question is about [] vs [10]. is [] ok?

Comment: @Gabriel Staples oh..sorry... some time ,I miss understand your question.I am java developer and know best knowledge about C++. but [10] only you assign only 10 character string. but c[] can , no limit of your string length . isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the member is private, nothing outside of the class should be able to mutate it. So neither piece of code should be used. Also, instead of using c-style arrays with c++, I would recommend you use the standard library `std::valarray` and `std::vector` for numerical and object data resp. and `std::string` for textual data.

You can read more about them in their docs.

As for your example:

```
class Object {
private:
    static int value[] = nullptr;

public:
   inline void setValue(int* newValue) {
        value = newValue;
    }
   inline int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

Object first{};
int a[10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
first.setValue(a)
std::cout << first.getValue(); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Object second{};

int b[1] = [1];
first.setValue(b)
std::cout << second.getValue(); // [1]
```

Comment: Sorry; bad example. In my real code I'm using a .h and .cpp file and this private variable is intended for use only within the class. The real question is about [] vs [10]. Is [] ok? Also, this is running on an 8-bit 16Mhz microcontroller. I'm not sure if std::valarray, std::vector, etc are available or wise to use on my device. I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Yeah man, it's fine. All [] does is initialize a nullptr, while [10] will allocate 10 whatevers and point the variable there.

Comment: Hey sorry about throwing you off with my bad question. I struggled a lot to even make sense of what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I'M WRONG, BUT THIS IS THE ANSWER THAT CLARIFIES MY CONFUSION THE MOST. Refer to the code comments, marked by `//<--`. These are my answer.  Is this correct?

.h file

```
class MyClass
{
  static char c[]; //<--this allocates memory for a pointer, 
                   //and makes it a null pointer since it doesn't
                   //point anywhere yet
};
```

.cpp file

```
char MyClass::c[] = "abcde"; //<--this allocates 6 bytes 
  //(5 chars + null terminator) for the string, AND now 
  //sets the above pointer to point to the starting byte
  //of this newly allocated memory.
```

Comment: These are *compile-time* deductions. In runtime, there should not be a point in which `c[]` is set to `nullptr`. The compiler should have already run through the entire source code at compile-time and figured out for itself the appropriate addresses to set for the correct variables.

Comment: Got it. I think my mistakes are all insightful; so I'll leave this "answer" as-is. This question was one of those rare times where I didn't know what my question really was until we got a discussion going.