# Cannot access members of a class

Tags: c++, class

I have a little problem, i probably included the class files wrongly, since i can't acces members of the enemy class. What am i doing wrong?
my cpp for class

```
#include "classes.h"

class Enemy
{
 bool alive;
 double posX,posY;
 int enemyNum;
 int animframe;
public:
Enemy(int col,int row)
{
    animframe = rand() % 2;
    posX = col*50;
    posY = row*50;
}

Enemy()
{

}
void destroy()
{
    alive = 0;
}
void setposX(double x)
{x = posX;}
void setposY(double y)
{y = posY;}
};
```

my header for class:

```
class Enemy;
```

my main:

```
#include "classes.h"
Enemy alien;
int main()
{
    alien. // this is where intelisense tells me there are no members
}
```

Comment: No data members or do you mean no function members as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your main file will only see what you wrote in the header, which is that `Enemy` is a class. Normally, you'd declare your whole class with fields and method signatures in the header files, and provide implementations in the .cpp file.

*classes.h*:

```
#ifndef _CLASSES_H_
#define _CLASSES_H_
class Enemy
{
    bool alive;
    double posX,posY;
    int enemyNum;
    int animframe;
public:
    Enemy(int col,int row);
    Enemy();
    void destroy();
    void setposX(double x);
    void setposY(double y);
};
#endif
```

*classes.cpp*:

```
#include "classes.h"
//....
void Enemy::destroy(){
    //....
}
//....
```

Comment: i cant access setPosX() too, i tried it with struct, no effect.

Comment: My bad. Initially I thought you were referring to fields.

Comment: so all variables normally go to .h file in their classes , while functions go to a seperate cpp file?

Comment: Normally yes, but there's also the issue of static fields (see [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/185844/469220)), and inline and template functions.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Vlad's answer, your file with main doesn't know anything about the Enemy class, other than that it exists.

In general, the class **declarations** goes in the header file, and the function **definitions** go in another.

Consider splitting the files like:

classes.h:

```
#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H

class Enemy
{
private:
    bool alive;
    double posX,posY;
    int enemyNum;
    int animframe;
public:
    Enemy(int col,int row);
    Enemy();
    void destroy();
    void setposX(double x);
    void setposY(double y);
};

#endif//CLASSES_H
```

Note the "include guards" which prevent the same file from being included more than once. Good practice to use on header files, or else you get annoying compilation errors.

classes.cpp:

```
#include "classes.h"

Enemy::Enemy(int col,int row)
{
    animframe = rand() % 2;
    posX = col*50;
    posY = row*50;
}

Enemy::Enemy()
{

}

void Enemy::destroy()
{
    alive = 0;
}

void Enemy::setposX(double x) {x = posX;}
void Enemy::setposY(double y) {y = posY;}
```