# Why should I initialize static class variables in C++?

Tags: c++, static-members

In C and C++ all static variables are initialized by default to ZERO.

This is not the case of static class data members. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int var;

class MyClass
{
public:
    static int classVar;
};
int MyClass::classVar = 0;  // Why I have to init it here?

int main(void)
{
    cout << ::var << endl;          // this is initalized to ZERO by default
    static int var;
    cout << var << endl;            // and this also is initalized to Zero
    cout << MyClass::classVar << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not sure **var** is initialized to 0. It's possible, sometimes probable, but not sure.

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato: Actually, the Standard is explicit about zeroing out memory for the all global variables before executing dynamic initialization... apart from those built-ins to which a literal value is affected, those I think can be affected directly (under the as-if rule) since it's unobservable.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

At class scope,

```
int MyClass::classVar = 0;  // Why I have to init it here?
```

is a **definition** and

```
static int classVar;
```

is a **declaration**, ie. a promise the variable will be **defined** somewhere: you must define *exactly once* the variables you declare.

The rationale is that the class declaration will likely be included in multiple source files. Would a part of it be a definition, it would take place multiply: this is erroneous (exceptions are inline [member] functions).

Note that according to value initialization rules, you can get along with

```
int MyClass::classVar;  // Zero-initialized !
```

as a definition.

Variables declared at namespace scope are definitions too (unless they are `extern` qualified):

```
int var;
```

is a declaration, and a definition: if you put this into a header and include it in multiple translation units, you have an error ("multiply defined symbol", or something along those lines).

*[Note that in C++ (and not in C), if the `var` above is `const`, it becomes automatically `static` and there is no violation of the One Definition Rule should it be put into a multiply included header. This goes slightly off topic, but feel free to ask details]*

Comment: I'm not sure that is what is being asked. I read that as "why do I have to put `= 0;` there?"

Comment: @Alexandre C.: It would be good if you also explain why that is needed.

Comment: So, `int MyClass::classVar;` should already suffice if you just require Zero-initialization? Never tried that but according to the Std and a deleted answer, it actually does.

Comment: "=0" is not mandatory. Even without this also it will initialize to zero only.

Comment: In case of **"int var** you said  ** if you put this into a header and include it in multiple translation units, you have an error ("multiply defined symbol", or something along those lines).** but doesn't #ifndef ... #define ... #endif guard avoid this problem (not saying you are wrong just wanted to make sure)

Comment: In summary, "Why I have to init it here?" -- No, u don't have to, u even shouldn't do so. 
[In common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/185848/1819810), declarations goes to header file `*.h`, while definition (or initialization) goes to source file `*.cpp`.

Comment: "The rationale is that the class declaration will likely be included in multiple source files." If there are braces after the class name, then that's a class definition, not a declaration. Classes are exempt from the ODR. I know Stroustrup himself said that rationale, but IMO it doesn't make much sense considering that you can initialize a non-static member variable inside a class(although it's treated as if you have written it in the member initialization list). Even then, you could just say `inline` and it will let you initialize a static member inside the class.

Answer (score 7):

C++ FAQ 10.12 states that:

> static data members must be explicitly defined in exactly one compilation unit.

[From C++ FAQ http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12)

Does that answer your question or were you after a reference to the C++ standard itself?

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize your static class data variables, because you have to tell the compiler what their value is. Classes need not have a notion of a default value.

Variables types have a logical "zero value", for `int` it is 0, for `double` 0.0, for a `string` "" etc. In contrast, classes do not necessarily have a default value. Consider, for example `class Rectangle`. What is its zero value - a rectangle with zero square or a rectangle with unit side length? For static variables, a compiler asks you to define yourself, what value your static variable must have, because not every data type can be initialized by a default value.

Comment: I think you are mistaken here: nothing prevents you from defining a static variable and not initializing it. If the variable is an instance of a class, then its constructor will be called.

Comment: The static variable have to be defined. Constructor will not initialize it. Consider below example... If "int test::k;" will be commented it will not compile.

class test

{

public:
        static int k;

};

int test::k;


int main()
{
        test t;
        cout<< t.k;

        return 0;
}

Comment: @victor Yes, you are right, thank you for noting that out to me. The question was about defining a static variable, and not its initialization.