# Using static variables of a C++ class across multiple Files

Tags: c++, class

I have class A such that:

```
class A {
    static int i;
    A();
    f1();
    f2();
    static void intitiaize();
    // snipped rest
}

void initialize() {
  A::i = 0;
}
```

in a header file.

I have a intiialize function for the class which initializes the
static variables in main method in second file.  After this i create
an object of `A` to call `a.f1()`.

When I try to create another object of `A` in file three the compiler complains
saying "no reference to class A". So included the header in this third file.

I get an error about multiple definitions of `A`.

How should I proceed? I have include guards around the class file.

Comment: I have added intiated  int A::i = 0 at end of class ..just missed it out here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a *declaration* of `A::i` in the header (and you can get rid of your `initialize()`:

```
//whatever.h:
class A{
    static int i;
    A();
    f1();
    f2();
    ...
}; // don't forget the semicolon on the end.
```

Then you need a definition of the variable in one CPP file:

```
// whatever.cpp:
int A::i = 0;
```

Then include the header wherever you're going to use objects of the class, and just compile the .CPP file and link it with the others that use this class.

Comment: thanks .. found another mistake n my code.. and stupid thing that I had done was to give function defn in header files .. this was again causing problem because the same defn was getting included in both the c files..

Answer (score 0):

With const integral numbers you can actually initialize it in the header. This includes bool and char types. Jerry's approach will work with any type and if it isn't const.

```
  class A{
      static const int i = 0;
      ...
  }
```

Comment: You are correct, changed it accordingly. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members) gives more details on the issue.