# Initializing private static variable in class

Tags: c++, class

I have a class in header file:

```
class Employee
    {
        //Private data members
    private:
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        char gender;

        //number of employees
        const static int numEmployees = 0;

    public: 
    ....
    };
```

**The dumb thing is in "GUIDELINE" from instructor said that declare numEmployees as a static integer value of 0 in private member of class**

Problem is I can't update `numEmployees` variable since it's `const`, for example when you declare Constructor in public: .. you can not increase `numEmployees = numEmployees + 1`.

If you don't declare `numEmployees` as `const`, just do `static int numEmployees;` visual studio 2010 give error said that only `const` will be declared in class.

Any idea how to declare `numEmployees`? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing private static members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members)

Comment: Nah, difference purpose, I've read that thread but! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `numEmployees` outside of the class as

```
Employee::numEmployees = 0
```

and declare it a `public` member in the class as

```
static int numEmployees;
```

You can also declare it `private` without intialization, as a static member is assigned zero by default.

Comment: I meant in class definition.put current declaration without const in public access.

Comment: The dump thing is in "GUIDELINE" from instructor said that declare numEmployees as a static integer value of 0 in private member of class

Comment: static member is initialized with 0 always

Answer (score 6):

Since `numEmployees` is going to change, it should not be `const`. Non-const static variables have to be initialized outside of the class declaration, for example in the source file, like so:

```
int Employee::numEmployees = 0;
```

that being said, `numEmployees` being a member of the `Employee` class is probably not the best idea.

And I would make `gender` an enum, not a char.

Comment: The dump thing is in "GUIDELINE" from instructor said that declare numEmployees as a static integer value of 0 in private member of class

Comment: @stijn We don't tag questions homework because that's what they *sound* like. Questions should only be tagged [homework] if someone is looking for homework-style answers (e.g., those that *hint* at the solution without providing actual working code). It's the asker's choice to tag his questions as (s)he pleases. Please do not try and force people to add this tag.

Comment: Never mind, I can accept that, "homework" make me feel good 'cause I dont have any hw for longtime. OK

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for pointing that out, I never actually read the whole story behind the homework tag.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, static variables needs to be declared in the class declaration but also defined in an implementation module.

```
// --- .h interface file
class MyClass
{
    public:
        static int my_static_variable;
    ...
};

// --- .cpp implementation file
#include "myclass.h"
int MyClass::my_static_variable = 0;
```

There is no real technical argument for this limitation, but it's how the language is defined.

If for some reason you really need to circumvent it, you can use function-level statics:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        // Note: returning a reference to int!
        static int& my_static_variable()
        {
            static int n = 0;
            return n;
        }
};
```

However, to access the variable, you will need in this case to formally call a method:

```
MyClass::my_static_variable() = 0;
MyClass::my_static_variable() ++;
MyClass::my_static_variable() *= 2;
```

I said "formally" because for such a simple function declared inline, the machine code generated by a decent compiler will be the same as the code needed to handle just a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared it as `const`. How can you change a const parameter ?

So you can have it as static and initialize to some value you want in the constructor. By default the static variables are initialized to zero.

Comment: The dump thing is in "GUIDELINE" from instructor said that declare numEmployees as a static integer value of 0 in private member of class