# C++: How to declare an empty private static vector inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, static, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Initializing private static members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members)

This is really driving me crazy, I want to declare a static private vector inside a class I am going to use as a shared memory.

My vector declaration goes like this:

```
private: static vector< pair< string, bool > > flags;
```

This is done inside a class, but how can I initialize it as empty vector? The best would be if the init would be in the class itself, because I need to use it in many places. The other option would be in `main()` but nothing more.

I have setFlag() and getFlag() methods that work with the vector, but it gives me all kinds of linker errors, because there is only declaration, no definition!

Comment: It will be empty by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have setFlag() and getFlag() methods that work with the vector, but
>   it gives me all kinds of linker errors, because there is only
>   declaration, no definition!

you need to initialise it in the class implementation file (or another source file):

```
vector< pair< string, bool > > MyClass::flags;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, although imo it's weird to be able to call `private` class members, even static ones.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a *definition* in the file that implements `YourClass`:

```
vector< pair< string, bool > > YourClass::flags;
```

This line will call the default constructor, which initializes an empty vector.