# C++ cannot initialize static data member

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I know this has been asked 10000 times, however, I'm still having issues getting this to compile.  Notice the static member 'map'.

In the 'getMap()' function, I receive an undefined reference error referring to the map data member.  **I attempted to move that function to a cpp file and declare 'map' in that file.  However, I then receive a conflicting definition error.**

Can somebody explain to me what is going on?  Thanks

Base.h

```
template<typename T> Base * createT() { return new T; }
typedef std::map<std::string, Base*(*)()> map_type;


class BaseFactory
{
    static Base* createInstance(std::string const& s)
    {
        map_type::iterator it = getMap()->find(s);
        if (it == getMap()->end())
            return 0;

        return it->second();
    }

protected:
    static map_type *getMap()
    {
        if (!map)
        {
            map = new map_type;
        }

        return map;
    }

private:
    static map_type * map;
     static Base* createInstance(std::string const* s);

public:
     BaseFactory();
     ~BaseFactory();

};
```

Comment: So in the 10001th time you missed the error message plus the actual line of code indicating the error

Comment: You misunderstood the advice you were given. The answer is not to move the function to the cpp file. The solution is to *add new code* to the cpp file. This new code defines the static member. How can such a simple thing be so difficult?

Comment: @john Thanks.  I got this working.  P.S. for everybody else, this question did not deserve the number of down votes received.

Comment: @tkcsam put your mouse cursor, on the down arrow button, and see why it deserved that

Comment: @P0W Funny, yet not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following declaration within a definition of your class is not enough:

```
private:
    static map_type * map;
```

In one .cpp file, you must also add:

```
map_type* BaseFactory::map = NULL;
```

This article might help you too: [Static data members (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr038.htm)
+ this question, which has almost 100k views by now: [Initializing private static members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/185844/1168156)

Comment: I didn't make my original point clear.  I wanted to keep everything in the header file, but I moved your suggestion beneath the class definition and it worked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @tkcsam: I've edited my answer to make it more clear.