# Proper place to initialize the value of static member variable

Tags: c++

Is it proper to initialize my static member variable in the constructor class?

```
// CFoo.h
class CFoo
{
public:
    CFoo();
    ~CFoo();
    static std::string str;
};

// CFoo.cpp
CFoo::CFoo()
{
    str = "HELLO";
}

CFoo::~CFoo()
{
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't `define` static member yet. You need to define it in CFoo.cpp.

CFoo.cpp

```
std::string CFoo::str;  // define str

CFoo::CFoo()

{
    str = "HELLO";  // reset str is fine
}

CFoo::~CFoo()
{
}
```