# visual studio can not find std:map during linkage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stl

In my console application, I am using stl map. when I am compiling it with visual studio 2012, I am getting the error that map is not found during compilation.

```
 Error  1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::map<int,int,struct std::less<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<int const ,int> > > m_headerDataMap" (?m_headerDataMap@FileHeader@@0V?$map@HHU?$less@H@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBHH@std@@@2@@std@@A)  c:\Users\m\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\FileReader\FileReader\FileReader.obj   FileReader
```

should I add a library to project? If yes, which one and how.

I defined map as follow:

```
 static map<int, int> m_headerDataMap;
```

Comment: Is that the whole error?  It doesn't seem to have an end `"`.

Comment: `map` is a header-only library so you shouldn't be getting a link error at all. Can you include the full error message? I suspect that you may have declared the instance of the `map` in a strange way.

Comment: @the_mandrill added more information to question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have code like

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    //...
private:
    static std::map<int, int> data;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass m;
}
```

You will end up with similar linker errors:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class
>   std::map,class std::allocator > > MyClass::data" ...

You need to define it somewhere.
e.g. in a cpp the file

```
std::map<int, int> MyClass::data;
```

See previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members)

Answer (score 2):

You do not normally have to add anything extra to a VS project to get the C++ standard library included.  Check that you haven't got anything inappropriate set in the linker 'input' options in the project's properties.  (There are several 'ignore' options in there).

You don't mention any compilation problems, but also make sure you're not overlooking the compiler screaming warnings at you about some earlier problem with this call.

Comment: Thanks. There is no compilation problem and there is no warning.

Answer (score -1):

Check the below link for various reasons of unresolved external symbol

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx