# static members and encapsulation in c++

Tags: c++, encapsulation, static-members, static-initialization

Let us assume the following class:

```
class FileManipulator
{
    static InputTypeOne * const fileone;
    InputTypeTwo *filetwo;

    public:
    FileManipulator( InputTypeTwo *filetwo )
    {
        this->filetwo = filetwo;
    }
    int getResult();
};
```

`FileManipulator` uses data from both files to obtain output from `getResult()`. This means multiple iterations over `filetwo` and multiple constructions of `FileManipulators` via iterations for different `InputTypeTwo` objects. Inputs are, let us say, some .csv databases. `InputTypeOne` remains the same for the whole task.

The program itself is multi-modular and the operation above is only its small unit.

My question is how can I handle that `static` field in accordance with the object-oriented paradigm and encapsulation. The field must be initialized somehow since it is not a fixed value over different program executions. As far as I understand C++ rules I cannot create a method for setting the field, but making it public and initializing it outside of any class (`FileManipulator` or a befriended class) seems to me at odds with the encapsulation.

What can I do then? The only thing that comes to my mind is to do it in a C manner, namely initialize it in an isolated enough compilation unit. Is it really all I can do? How would that be solved in a professional manner?

### edit

I corrected pointer to constant to constant pointer, which was my initial intention.

Comment: `static` members can also be `protected` or `private`.

Comment: I know, but how would I initialize them then?

Comment: How do you initialize non-static members?

Comment: Its really not clear fromteh description why you would even want to use a static field, instead of a member variable. Most OO texts I have read frown on class variables, which is what being static here provides.

Comment: In constructor. The point is that static member initialization cannot be placed in any function body.

Comment: so, generally you initialize class statics much the same way you initialize global variables.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett because it doesn't change for the whole program run and once defined it is the same for all objects of the class, which there would be abundance of.

Comment: I declared fileOne as non-static, but private, created a getter/setter for its manipulation, and the setter throwed and exception in case of a second call.

Comment: So, if you can, initialize it, like a global, in FileManipulator.cpp. 
Else, use an init function and check./all it during the object constructor, as per Max.

Comment: @Constructor post then an answer that compiles

Comment: pvgoran has already done it. See his answer.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett yes, like I posted that was the solution I was thinking of and wondered for alternative (speaking of global variable in compilation unit). The Max's solution is an idea, but it doesn't seem to include the fact that fileone shouldn't be altered, ie the const constraint.

Comment: Do you know about casting operator `const_cast`?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a public static method of FileManipulator that would initialize the field for you:

```
static void init()
{
  fileone = something();
}
```

And then call it from main() or some place where your program is being initialized.

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous Why do you think so?

Comment: @Constructor If you try to compile it you'll get a linker error. You must create the static variable before you will assign value to it. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous Of course, you should also write smth like this: `const InputTypeOne *FileManipulator::fileone;` in `*.cpp` file. And?

Comment: @Constructor have you even read the question? I do say there that it seems at odds with encapsulation, and therefore might be unnecessarily risky. Normally you keep such things private to restrict access. I asked if making it global within compilation unit is the only solution.

Comment: @Constructor Also, it wouldn't work for a const field obviously, which is here the case.

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous I can't understand why this solution does not suit you.

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous It would work. Don't confuse a constant pointer and a pointer to a constant. The last one is used in your code and it is not a constant.

Comment: @Constructor my bad. I meant the first, sorry. :/

Comment: Declaring a static variable like `const InputTypeOne *FileManipulator::fileone;` has nothing to do with; it's like a part of class definition (and should be done in a .cpp file related to the class).

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous if you want a constant pointer, you'll need to initialize it in the same .cpp file like this: `InputTypeOne *const FileManipulator::fileone = something();`. But that's not a good idea because you can't control when initialization will happen. What's the problem with having a **private** non-constant pointer? Noone from outside the class will be able to access it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this which comes to mind is:

In the .cpp file

```
FileManipulator::fileone = NULL;
```

Then modify constructor to do the following:

```
FileManipulator( InputTypeTwo *filetwo,  InputTypeOne  *initValue = NULL)
{
    if(fileone == NULL)
    {
        fileone = initValue;
    }
    this->filetwo = filetwo;
 }
```

Or you could also define an init function and make sure to call it before using the class and after the CTOR. the init function will include the logic of how to init fileone.

Comment: How would such init function work? I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members as I cannot initialize static members in function bodies.

Comment: You can call a static function, from a none static function. The other way around won't work.

What I suggest is similar to the code written in the constructor, just moved to a side function which will do the init only once. (any subsequent calls will do nothing if made)