# Can I uniformly initialize a static const member of template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that looks something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class foo
{
    static const T arr[16];
};
```

The contents of `foo<T>::arr` are numerically identical for all types `T` that I plan to use. For example, I would initialize it for `T = float` and `T = double` by placing lines in a source file as follows:

```
float foo<float>::arr[16] = {1, 2, 3, 4, ...};
double foo<double>::arr[16] = {1, 2, 3, 4, ...};
```

Is there a way that I can initialize this in one place without having to repeat myself and enumerate all of the types that `T` can take on? Note that since the type of each array element is `T`, I can't use the trick of deriving `foo<T>` from a non-template base class that holds the static array.

Comment: You could use a `define`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried?  This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    static T const arr[16];
};

template<typename T>
T const Foo<T>::arr[16] = {1,2,3,4};

int main() {
    for ( float const *f = Foo<float>::arr; f != Foo<float>::arr+16; ++f ) {
        cout << *f << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for ( double const *d = Foo<double>::arr; d != Foo<double>::arr+16; ++d ) {
        cout << *d << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the problem of multiple instantiations of the static variable that can occur when you initialize it in a header file ([described here, for instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members)). I think that this method would trigger that problem if the declaration of `foo<T>` was in a header that was included by multiple compilation units.

Comment: Why not `for(auto d = std::begin(Foo<double>::arr); d != std::end(Foo<double>::arr); ++d )`.... or why not `for(auto const & i : Foo<double>::arr)`

Comment: @Nawaz, I'm sticking with C++03, since the question was'nt tagged as C++11.  If I were working in C++11, I would have written it that way.

Comment: @JasonR: The rules are different for templates.  The multiple generated definitions in separate translation units should be coalesced into single definitions by the linker.  If a compiler/linker emitted an error for this with a template, that would be nonconforming.