# Eliminate warning "construction of local static object is not thread-safe"

Tags: c++

I have the following class:

```
struct globalAllocated 
{
    void operator delete(void*p)
    {
        static HANDLE heap= GetHeap();
        ::HeapFree(heap, 0, p);
    }
}
```

warning C4640: 'heap' : construction of local static object is not thread-safe

I thought about using some synchronization with mutex but it seems costly.

Making the heap a private member won't work because the operator delete override must be static, so heap must be private- but if I declare it as a static class member, there is no where for me to initialize it.

What's the best solution?

Comment: “but if I declare it as a static class member, there is no where for me to initialize it.” – [yes there is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/185844/1968).

Comment: you'll probably need to make HeapFree thread-safe anyway. At that point, there wouldn't necessarily  be an extra cost making 'delete' thread-safe

Comment: There is no cpp file. This isn't c++11. The class will be used as a parameter to a template as a custom allocator, so no one will actually call it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++11, it's required to be thread-safe there.  (But that could easily be implemented by using a mutex as well, if you're concerned about performance issues.)

More generally: try to ensure that the function is called before multiple threads are started.  (In many applications, all that is needed is to call it somewhere in the initialization of a static object.)

Comment: Compling as C++ also has this warning in MSVC2015 update 2