# Error accessing static private variable in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I wish to access a static variable declared in a class. Following this [post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members) suggestions, I defined two files,

in test.h:

```
class foo
{
    private:
        static int i;
};
```

in test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int foo::i = 0;
}
```

But, the compiler still generates this error when I do `make test`. I'm using a mac:

```
test.cpp:16:11: error: definition or redeclaration of 'i' not allowed inside a function
    int foo::i = 0;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It is private member which means other functions including main() cant access it. you need to write `int foo::i=0`  in global scope

Comment: The answers in that post declared the variable as private, so I assumed it is correct. It also makes sense to me that the variable should be public.

Comment: you don't need to make it public , you can write a `static` public member  function which access the value and change it in `main()`

Comment: if `static int i;` is important for `foo ` class mechanism of work so better not to expose it to public but change it by static function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `int foo::i = 0;` belongs at global scope, not in `main`
2. Because it is `private`, `main` will not be able to access it. You'll have to make the access specifier less restrictive (i.e. `public`) or make an accessor function for it.

Comment: ...or add `main` as a `friend`.

Answer (score 3):

> ... The definition for a `static` data member shall appear in a namespace
>   scope enclosing the member’s class definition. ...

(C++14 standard, [class.static.data]/1).

You cannot define a static member at block scope, as you have attempted to do.

If you want `main` to have access to the private member, write a public accessor function. Or make `main` a friend (probably a worse idea).

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers here:
Constant static members can be initialized inside the class definition if they are of integral or enumerated type:

```
struct X {
const static int n = 1;
const static int m{2}; // since C++11
};
```