# Access to private static function during static member initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, static-methods, static-members

I have a class with a static member. This will be initialized using a private static function of the same class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    static std::string const s;

private:
    static std::string make()
    {
        return "S";
    }
};

std::string const A::s = A::make();

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::s << std::endl;
    // std::cout << A::make() << std::endl; // <-- Does not work
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: Because of which rule is this allowed? Clearly the commented part does not work, because I am not allowed to access a private function from outside the class. So why is the initialization of the private static member during startup a special case? (And on a side note: what is the intention of this rule? Is it to allow this exact case?)

I am aware of other mechanisms to initialize a static member (like here: [Initializing private static members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members)). But in my case the member is const, so as far as I know the only way to set it is via direct initalization at the place of definition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the initialization of a static data member is considered part of the characterization of the class even though the static data member is defined at namespace scope (outside the class definition).

From the standard, [class.static.data#note-1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.static.data#note-1):

> [*Note [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.static.data#note-1)*: The [*initializer*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.general#nt:initializer) in the definition of a static data member is
> in the scope of its class ([[basic.scope.class]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.class)). — *end note*]
>
> [*Example [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.static.data#example-1)*:
>
> ```
> class process {
>   static process* run_chain;
>   static process* running;
> };
>
> process* process::running = get_main();
> process* process::run_chain = running;
> ```
>
> The definition of the static data member `run_­chain` of class `process`
> inhabits the global scope; the notation `process​::​run_­chain`
> indicates that the member `run_­chain` is a member of class `process` and
> in the scope of class `process`. In the static data member definition,
> the [*initializer*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.general#nt:initializer) expression refers to the static data member `running` of
> class `process`. — *end example*]

Comment: You are right about the const. Edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: I think that would be clearer as "The initialization of a static data member is considered part of the characterization of the class even though the static data member is defined at namespace scope (outside the class definition)."  (I used "characterization" because "class definition" has a very formal meaning in the C++ standard.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Fine.