# Arduino: Accessing static variable in the class's static method

Tags: class, arduino, static-methods, static-variables

What I want to do is simply;

- Using a static class without instantiating  (preferable a
  Singleton)
- And setting some static class variables within some static
  setter/getter.

It look super easy but I couldn't find any example on the internet wired.
Whatever I do gives; undefined reference to `Test::_pin' error!
I does NOT compile.

My class header Test.h:

```
#ifndef Test_h
#define Test_h
#include "Arduino.h"

class Test
{
    public:
    Test(byte pin);
    static byte getPin();
    static byte _pin;    

    private:

};
#endif
```

My class code Test.cpp:

```
#include "Test.h"

Test::Test (byte pin) {
    _pin = pin;
}

byte Test::getPin(){
    return _pin;
}
```

StaticClassTest.ino:

```
#include "Test.h"

void setup()
{
    Test(5);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println(Test::getPin(), DEC);
}
void loop() { }
```

I've already tried to access _pin with:

```
byte Test::getPin(){
    return Test::_pin;  // did NOT work, reference error
}
```

Ideally, _pin should be in private: and accessible by my getPin();
But as it is impossible to set/get this variable I put in public to have more chance.

**What is wrong in this simple context?**

**How can I set/get this variable in this class?**

Answer (score 4):

In `Test.cpp` add:

```
byte Test::_pin;
```

and it'll work.

It's just declaration inside of class, and you have to make a space for this variable too (by adding definition).

More info in [similar Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members) and [all possibilities on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

Comment: Thank you @KIIV with this second definition in Test.cpp it worked! I'm still surprised and confused. Why we need this second memory allocation? I spent around 6 hours because of this exception :-/ again, thank you! Cheers,