# Static, private member of a class internal type

Tags: c++, c++11, static, c++14

I've a class `myClass` that has a type defined in it, `myType`, and a `static const std::map` that uses this type. How must I initialise the member?

The situation is like this. The compiler tells me: `multiple definition of MyClass::myMap`. But there is really only one definition. Is this initialisation (schematically)  correct?

```
class myClass
{
  struct myType
  {
    // ...
  };
  static const std::map<int, myType> myMap;
};

const std::map<int, myType> myClass::myMap = {
  {1, {"hello myType", 99, "woops"}},
  {2, {"hello again", 66, "holla"}},
  {3, {"and bye", 33, "adios"}}
};
```

**It's not a duplicate because the `const` members in the proposed question are not static.**

Also this question: [Initializing private static members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members)
does not answer the question since the `static const` members are `int`'s.

Comment: You forgot the `;` after struct

Comment: Is it really `const myClass::std::map<int, myType> myMap` and not `const std::map<int, myType> myClass::myMap`? The first one shouldn't compile because there is no `myClass::std::map`.

Comment: I fixed them both, it was not present in my code and thus not the problem.

Comment: Agreed, this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Add myClass like so :  `const std::map<int, myClass::myType> myClass::myMap = {` Compiles for me.

Comment: Your sampe initialization is correct but it needs to not be in a header file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, both the declaration and definition are in the same file.  If you do this, and you "#include" the file in more than one place, there will be multiple definitions created.

The static value is typically initialized separately, in a C++ source file and not in the header file with the class.