# Declare / initialize static member of private nested struct

Tags: c++, static, inner-classes, private-members

I have this example code (in a file named `A.cpp`):

```
class O {
private:
    struct S {
        int i;
        int j;
    };

    static struct S s;
};

O::S s { 0, 1 };
```

I compile with `g++ -c -std=c++11 A.cpp` from the command line on my Mac and I get the following error:

```
A.cpp:11:4: error: 'S' is a private member of 'O'
O::S s { 0, 1 };
   ^
A.cpp:3:9: note: declared private here
        struct S {
               ^
1 error generated
```

The problem originally arose in more complicate code on a linux machine with essentially the same error. (In the "real" code the class declaration is in a header instead of all in one file, but, again, the error is the same.)

This seems like it should work.  Certainly `S` is declared private, as the message indicates, but it is only being used in the context of the private member variable `s`.  What's wrong here and why?

EDIT: With regard to the claimed duplicate at [How to initialize private static members in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c), the apparent difference is the scope of the inner class rather than generically how to initialize a static member variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize private static members in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c)

Comment: @user657267 I had seen that question, but it didn't have the additional issue of the inner class, which was the ultimate problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
O::S s { 0, 1 };
```

Attempts to define an object `::s` of the type `O::S`. It's not a definition of the static member. That one will look like this:

```
O::S O::s { 0, 1 };
```

Comment: I made a small edit, but this was the problem.  One set of colons for the type and then the (missing) set for the scope of `s`.  Thanks!

Comment: @Brick - Oh yeah, thanks for the edit! I guess I'm a bit drowsy :)

Answer (score -1):

S class is declared in the private section of O so code outside the class O can't access it. Specifically, you can't instantiate class S outside class O since that would constitute accessing a private declaration.

If you want to be able to create instances if S outside class O, you should declare it public.