# Why do I have to declare a static vector?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm supposed to make a class which has a static vector as a variable.

```
   using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    static vector<Player> PLAYERS;
};
```

In the .cpp file I got an undefined reference to the vector and I have been told I have to declare it first

```
vector<Player> Foo::PLAYERS;
```

My question is what does that declaration excactly do? Is it similar to the constructor of a class? If the vector wasn't static would I still have to declare it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1. See particularly Matt Curstis' answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/185863/5470596

Comment: You've got the vocabulary mixed up. That vector is declared (but not defined) in the class. The statement you added is the definition.

Comment: you _need_ to define static membre when you don't want them to be default constructed

Comment: @Tyker You also need to define them when you *do* want them default constructed, unless they're `constexpr` or a "compile-time only constant integral value."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header file, you *declared* the vector. That vector has the keyword `static`, thus every instance of the class `Foo` will share that one and only vector.

You need to *define* the vector as well. You cannot do it outside the class, since this will result in a compiler error. Thus, in your source file, you wrote:

```
vector<Player> Foo::PLAYERS;
```

which is the *definition*.

I wouldn't say that it is similar to a constructor, but rather like because there can be only one instance of your vector (thus you cannot have it in the constructor of `Foo`).

I like to think it like the case of a variable declared as `extern` in a header file, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot that really helped out. One more thing: Do I have to use the :: operator every time I use the vector ( Foo::PLAYERS ... ) Or can I just use PLAYERS ...   without a calling the class everytime?

Comment: Good @Default99. You are not *calling* the class. This operator `::` is for scope resolution. If you are not taught what this operator does yet in your school, then be patient and trust your instructor. ;) PS: There is always the Internet, if you are that eager . .

Comment: Trusting the instructor is somewhat risky when it comes to C++, some do that a lot better than others. If in doubt, get a good C++ book you can really trust.

Comment: @Default99 within the members of `Foo` the name `PLAYERS` refers to that vector, and using `Foo::PLAYERS` is redundant.

Comment: I find the statement about the constructor misleading. When you define `vector<Player> Foo::PLAYERS;`, the compiler do add code (executed at some point before entering the `main` function) to call the default constructor of `vector`, initialising it to an empty vector.