# Initializing private static compound constexpr values

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, compiler-warnings

I know it's [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c) that class declarations should be in the header file and class member initialization should be in the source file. However, since my struct object (`compound`) is declared as `static constexpr`, I believe I can define it within the header file (shown below).

header1.h:

```
namespace common
{
   namespace abc
   {
      struct compound
      {
         unsigned int intgr1;
         unsigned int intgr2;
         unsigned int intgr3;
      };
   }
}
```

test.h:

```
#include "header1.h"

namespace common
{
   namespace def
   {
      class xyz
      {
         // public: ...

         private:
            static constexpr abc::compound foo = 
               {0, 1, 2}; // <--- C4268 warning here
      };
   }
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

namespace common
{
   namespace def
   {
      constexpr abc::compound xyz::foo;
   }
}
```

However, this gives me a level 4 compiler (MSVS 2015) warning (C4268 - shown above in test.h) stating:

```
'private: static common::abc compound common::def::xyz::foo':'const' 
static/global data initialized with compiler generated constructor fills the   
object with zeros
```

What does this warning mean? Is there a better way of initializing this struct?

Comment: Question with that recommendation is rather outdated (2008) while VS2015 does not even support `constexpr` properly. With C++17 there is no need to define `foo` in `test.cpp` because `static` class fields can be inline.

Comment: maybe i am just a bit confused by your namespaces, but isnt `common::def::xyz::foo` (in the header) completely unrelated to `common::def::foo` (the one in the source) ?

Comment: @user463035818 yes I believe you are correct. Edited.

Comment: I can't reproduce that warning: https://godbolt.org/z/OYFlyd (note, that gcc and clang are complaining that you are missing direct call to default constructor, but adding it doesn't change much).

Comment: @MichałŁoś I'm not familiar with godbolt but I noticed you added in curly brackets {} for the constexpr intializers in the source file. Removing that and then adding in the xyz:: scope operator (recent edit) should remove those complaints (although I don't think the warning is being reproduced on this site - perhaps because level 4 warnings aren't activated?)

Comment: @SteveCho: yes, I've added them to make it compile on clang and gcc. I've added /Wall to MSVC, and it seems that in C++17 it does copy-elide as it should: https://godbolt.org/z/p3mDzf (checked on newest MSVC). On older one it seems to be a bug, because when you remove '=' in line 24 it still generates the same warning on MSVC 2015: https://godbolt.org/z/mAJflU

Comment: @MichałŁoś the '=' is not necessary. I believe initializing structs can be done with or without it. So removing it on line 24 should still generate the same warning as it changes nothing.