# Static member of class with private constructor

Tags: c++

I'm making class, that should help with minor deficiencies of C++, like comparing `double` with other `double` with defined precision, and so on.

I have namespace `Utilities`, where `class Double` exists:

```
namespace Utilities {

void init();

class Double {
public:
    //! @brief Compares the equality of two doubles with defined precision
    static bool fuzzyCompare(const double &d1,const double &d2);

    static void setFuzzyComparePrecision(int precision);
private:
    //! @brief Private constructor
    Double() {};

    static int fuzzyComparePrecision_;
};

}
```

I want this `class` to contain only `static` members and not be instantiable. Current idea is to call `Utilities::init()` function in `void main()`, which initializes default values for members of `class Double`.

Is it possible to set default `fuzzyComparePrecision_` without calling function `init()` in `void main()`? Or in other words, is it possible to set default value of `fuzzyComparePrecision_` without instance of `Double` and without calling other function such as `init()`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: BTW. Why do you create a class for that? Free functions would be nicer here (unless you need to unit test this, but you can't substitute singleton like this anyway).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen But, how can I initialize static members? When I do it in class definition, there is error during compilation, because my static members are not constant and I can't set value for them in .cpp file, because those members are private.

Comment: Another BTW, `main()` returns `int` in standard C++, not `void`.   It is possible to initialise static class members by defining them with an initialiser outside the class definition (in exactly one compilation unit)

Comment: @Peter I know, but within this context, it doesn't matter

Comment: @Brykyz It does matter.  `void main()` is ill-formed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize private static members in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen BTW, I use classes because I want to keep some variables in private context. If I use free functions, I would need to use global variables, and I don't want it.

Comment: Why don't you make Double a namespace and implement all of those as functions? After all, that is what they are. Doing it with a class looks pretty much like Java style - are you coming from there? Other than that, the init function looks like code smell. The code should work even when somebody forgot about this. If you want to use constants, better have variables with the `constexpr` keyword, or, in your contex, use something like `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`.

Comment: In addition, if you want to use private variables like you wrote a moment ago, consider declaring them in the corresponding source file. Depends on the context. If we talk about a double precision threshold, and you really want to hide it for some reason, go with a `constexpr` in the source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not only possible, it's *(almost)* required to do so.**

Starting from C++17, you can declare any static variable as `inline`, and initialize it in class body:

```
class Double {
private:
    inline static int fuzzyComparePrecision_ = 0;
};
```

---

Before C++17, every* static class member requires an out-of-class definition.

It can (and usually should) be combined with initialization, to avoid dealing with uninitialized variables.

You have to provide the following (in cpp file):

```
int Utilities::Double::fuzzyComparePrecision_;
```

But you can also extend it with initialization:

```
int Utilities::Double::fuzzyComparePrecision_ = 0;
```

*There are exceptions - `const` `static` members can be initialized in class body with another constant expression.

Comment: You can make it `inline` now too

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Added that :)

Answer (score 2):

To initialize static member variables you have two ways:

1. If you are using C++17 you can do this with `inline static` member variables:

   ```
   class Double {
   private:
       inline static int fuzzyComparePrecision_ = 2;
   }
   ```
2. For earlier version of C++ you have to do it outside the class declaration in a source file (it can't be in a header file):

   ```
   class Double {
   private:
       static int fuzzyComparePrecision_;
   }
   ```

   ```
   int Double::fuzzyComparePrecision_ = 2;
   ```

Comment: _"To make your class not instanciable, declare it as static"_ Can you link us to a live demo of this working?

Comment: Just curious, is there any big difference between those ways? In other words, are there any cases which requires first or second solution?

Comment: @Brykyz There are two differences: The first method is only available in modern C++17 compilers; The first method can be used in header files and eases the creation of header-only libraries.

Comment: Other than that no. I still quite like out-of-class definitions, personally, but in practice it's hard to think of an objective reason to use them nowadays, at least in the sense that they have no notable advantages over the `inline` variety that I can think of

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for pointing out that static classes can be instantiated. I never tried that before and somehow assumed that obviously this must be the usage of the keyword. Was just always a bit wondering about why do members still have to be marked as static explicitly... ;)

Comment: @YanB. It's more that static classes _don't exist_. `static class` is [not a thing](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96e553eba30c14b1) that you can write in a well-formed C++ program*. Please don't write random guesses/assumptions into answers!

Comment: * Except for unrelated cases like `static class T {} obj;` :D (there it's the instance `obj` that's static)