# Initializing Private Properties (Value / Reference / Static) in C++ Class

Tags: c++, oop

```
class A
{
private:
int x ;
int &y ;
static int z ;

};
```

How can initialize these 3 variable in this class

Comment: So what have you tried already?

Comment: Do you want to initialize the variables from a constructor? It seem like you may need to provide more context to get a helpful answer.

Comment: There are many ways to initialize the variables, used in different contexts.  Please provide more information about how this class is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize private static members in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The normal variable can be initialized in the constructor, in its member initializer list, but you don't have to:

```cpp
A::A(int i) :
    x(i) { /* c'tor */ }
```

The reference can only be initialized from the constructor, and you **must** initialize it:

```cpp
A::A(int& r) :
    y(r) { /* c'tor */ }
```

Now the y field of A will reference to the same variable as r, it is not a copy of it.

The static variable must be initialized outside the class, probably in a separate source file, you must do this if you want access that static variable.

```cpp
int A::z = 0;
```