# extern "C" Demangling Causing Strange Linker Errors

Tags: c++, c, wrapper, extern

I have the following header file

*possion_surface_reconstructor.h*

```
#ifndef POISSON_SURFACE_RECONSTRUCTOR_H
#define POISSON_SURFACE_RECONSTRUCTOR_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

#include "../core/PreProcessor.h"
#include "../core/MyMiscellany.h"
#include "../core/CmdLineParser.h"
#include "../core/PPolynomial.h"
#include "../core/FEMTree.h"
#include "../core/Ply.h"
#include "../core/PointStreamData.h"
#include "../core/Image.h"

#include "callbacks.h"

namespace MeshingAdapter
{

    #undef USE_DOUBLE                               // If enabled, double-precesion is used
    #define DATA_DEGREE 0                           // The order of the B-Spline used to splat in data for color interpolation
    #define WEIGHT_DEGREE 2                         // The order of the B-Spline used to splat in the weights for density estimation
    #define NORMAL_DEGREE 2                         // The order of the B-Spline used to splat in the normals for constructing the Laplacian constraints
    #define DEFAULT_FEM_DEGREE 1                    // The default finite-element degree
    #define DEFAULT_FEM_BOUNDARY BOUNDARY_NEUMANN   // The default finite-element boundary type
    #define DIMENSION 3     

    cmdLineParameter< char* >
        In("in"),
        Out("out"),
        TempDir("tempDir"),
        Grid("grid"),
        Tree("tree"),
        Transform("xForm");

    cmdLineReadable
        Performance("performance"),
        ShowResidual("showResidual"),
        NoComments("noComments"),
        PolygonMesh("polygonMesh"),
        NonManifold("nonManifold"),
        ASCII("ascii"),
        Density("density"),
        LinearFit("linearFit"),
        PrimalGrid("primalGrid"),
        ExactInterpolation("exact"),
        Normals("normals"),
        Colors("colors"),
        InCore("inCore"),
        Verbose("verbose");

    cmdLineParameter< int >
#ifndef FAST_COMPILE
        Degree("degree", DEFAULT_FEM_DEGREE),
#endif // !FAST_COMPILE
        Depth("depth", 8),
        KernelDepth("kernelDepth"),
        Iters("iters", 8),
        FullDepth("fullDepth", 5),
        BaseDepth("baseDepth", 0),
        BaseVCycles("baseVCycles", 1),
#ifndef FAST_COMPILE
        BType("bType", DEFAULT_FEM_BOUNDARY + 1),
#endif // !FAST_COMPILE
        MaxMemoryGB("maxMemory", 0),
#ifdef _OPENMP
        ParallelType("parallel", (int)ThreadPool::OPEN_MP),
#else // !_OPENMP
        ParallelType("parallel", (int)ThreadPool::THREAD_POOL),
#endif // _OPENMP
        ScheduleType("schedule", (int)ThreadPool::DefaultSchedule),
        ThreadChunkSize("chunkSize", (int)ThreadPool::DefaultChunkSize),
        Threads("threads", (int)std::thread::hardware_concurrency());

    cmdLineParameter< float >
        DataX("data", 32.f),
        SamplesPerNode("samplesPerNode", 1.5f),
        Scale("scale", 1.1f),
        Width("width", 0.f),
        Confidence("confidence", 0.f),
        ConfidenceBias("confidenceBias", 0.f),
        CGSolverAccuracy("cgAccuracy", 1e-3f),
        PointWeight("pointWeight");

    cmdLineReadable* params[] =
    {
    #ifndef FAST_COMPILE
        &Degree,
        &BType,
    #endif // !FAST_COMPILE
        &In,
        &Depth,
        &Out,
        &Transform,
        &Width,
        &Scale,
        &Verbose,
        &CGSolverAccuracy,
        &NoComments,
        &KernelDepth,
        &SamplesPerNode,
        &Confidence,
        &NonManifold,
        &PolygonMesh,
        &ASCII,
        &ShowResidual,
        &ConfidenceBias,
        &BaseDepth,
        &BaseVCycles,
        &PointWeight,
        &Grid,
        &Threads,
        &Tree,
        &Density,
        &FullDepth,
        &Iters,
        &DataX,
        &Colors,
        &Normals,
        &LinearFit,
        &PrimalGrid,
        &TempDir,
        &ExactInterpolation,
        &Performance,
        &MaxMemoryGB,
        &InCore,
        &ParallelType,
        &ScheduleType,
        &ThreadChunkSize,
        NULL
    };

    class PoissonSurfaceReconstructor
    {
    public:
        PoissonSurfaceReconstructor(
            ProgressCallback& progressCallback,
            WarningCallback& warningCallback,
            ErrorCallback& errorCallback);

        bool ExecuteSurfaceReconstruction(int argc, char* argv[]);

    private:
        template< unsigned int Dim, class Real >
        struct FEMTreeProfiler;

        template< unsigned int Dim, typename Real >
        struct ConstraintDual;

        template< unsigned int Dim, typename Real >
        struct SystemDual;

        template< unsigned int Dim >
        struct SystemDual< Dim, double >;

        template< class Real, typename ... SampleData, unsigned int ... FEMSigs >
        int Execute(int argc, char* argv[], UIntPack< FEMSigs ... >);

        template< unsigned int Dim, class Real, typename ... SampleData >
        int Execute(int argc, char* argv[]);

        template< typename Real, unsigned int Dim >
        int WriteGrid(ConstPointer(Real) values, int res, const char* fileName);

        template< typename Vertex, typename Real, typename SetVertexFunction, unsigned int ... FEMSigs, typename ... SampleData >
        int ExtractMesh(
            UIntPack< FEMSigs ... >,
            std::tuple< SampleData ... >,
            FEMTree< sizeof ... (FEMSigs), Real >& tree,
            const DenseNodeData< Real, UIntPack< FEMSigs ... > >& solution,
            Real isoValue,
            const std::vector< typename FEMTree< sizeof ... (FEMSigs),
            Real >::PointSample >* samples,
            std::vector< MultiPointStreamData< Real, PointStreamNormal< Real, DIMENSION >,
            MultiPointStreamData< Real, SampleData ... > > >* sampleData,
            const typename FEMTree< sizeof ... (FEMSigs), Real >::template DensityEstimator< WEIGHT_DEGREE >* density,
            const SetVertexFunction& SetVertex,
            std::vector< std::string >& comments,
            XForm< Real, sizeof...(FEMSigs) + 1 > iXForm);

        template< class Real, unsigned int Dim >
        XForm< Real, Dim + 1 > GetBoundingBoxXForm(Point< Real, Dim > min, Point< Real, Dim > max, Real scaleFactor);

        template< class Real, unsigned int Dim >
        XForm< Real, Dim + 1 > GetBoundingBoxXForm(
            Point< Real, Dim > min,
            Point< Real, Dim > max,
            Real width,
            Real scaleFactor,
            int& depth);

        template< class Real, unsigned int Dim >
        XForm< Real, Dim + 1 > GetPointXForm(InputPointStream< Real, Dim >& stream, Real width, Real scaleFactor, int& depth);

        template< class Real, unsigned int Dim >
        XForm< Real, Dim + 1 > GetPointXForm(InputPointStream< Real, Dim >& stream, Real scaleFactor);

        template<typename... Arguments>
        std::string FormatString(const std::string& fmt, const Arguments&... args);

        double Weight(double v, double start, double end);

        const float DefaultPointWeightMultiplier = 2.f;

        ProgressCallback _progressCallback;
        WarningCallback _warningCallback;
        ErrorCallback _errorCallback;
    };
}
#endif // POISSON_SURFACE_RECONSTRUCTOR_H
```

The .cpp file that back this class compiles fine. I can compile this code as an .exe and make some tweaks and it's what I want. However, I need this code to be called from C# so I create a wrapper class that is callable from C#

*configuration.h*

```
#ifndef MESHING_DLL_CONFIG_H
#define MESHING_DLL_CONFIG_H

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  define LIBRARY_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#  define LIBRARY_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ > 3
#  define LIBRARY_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#  define LIBRARY_IMPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#else
#  define LIBRARY_EXPORT
#  define LIBRARY_IMPORT
#endif

#ifdef LIBRARY_API_EXPORTS
#  define LIBRARY_API LIBRARY_EXPORT
#elif LIBRARY_API_IMPORTS
#  define LIBRARY_API LIBRARY_IMPORT
#else
#  define LIBRARY_API
#endif
#endif /* MESHING_DLL_CONFIG_H */
```

*wrappers.h*

```
#ifndef MESHING_WRAPPERS_H
#define MESHING_WRAPPERS_H

#include <exception>
#include "configuration.h"
#include "callbacks.h"
#include "poisson_surface_reconstructor.h"

typedef intptr_t ArrayHandle;

extern "C"
{
    LIBRARY_EXPORT bool ExecutePoissonSurfaceReconstruction(
        int argc, 
        char* argv[], 
        ProgressCallback progressCallback, 
        WarningCallback warningCallback, 
        ErrorCallback errorCallback);

    LIBRARY_EXPORT bool Release(ArrayHandle arrayHandle);
}
#endif // MESHING_WRAPPERS_H
```

*wrappers.cpp*

```
#include "wrappers.h"

using namespace MeshingAdapter;

LIBRARY_EXPORT bool ExecutePoissonSurfaceReconstruction(
    int argc,
    char* argv[],
    ProgressCallback progressCallback, 
    WarningCallback warningCallback, 
    ErrorCallback errorCallback)
{ 
    try
    {
        PoissonSurfaceReconstructor* poissonSurfaceRecon =
            new PoissonSurfaceReconstructor(
                progressCallback,
                warningCallback,
                errorCallback);
        bool success = poissonSurfaceRecon->ExecuteSurfaceReconstruction(argc, argv);
        delete poissonSurfaceRecon;
        return success;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        errorCallback(ex.what());
        return false;
    }
}

LIBRARY_EXPORT bool Release(ArrayHandle arrayHandle) 
{ 
    // #TODO can we do this smarter?
    return true;
}
```

However, the very inclusion of `possion_surface_reconstructor.h` causes 114 `LNK2005` errors, mainly from classes I reference from different projects. An example being

```
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static bool ThreadPool::_Close" (?_Close@ThreadPool@@0_NA) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static unsigned __int64 ThreadPool::DefaultChunkSize" (?DefaultChunkSize@ThreadPool@@2_KA) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::vector<class std::thread,class std::allocator<class std::thread> > ThreadPool::_Threads" (?_Threads@ThreadPool@@0V?$vector@Vthread@std@@V?$allocator@Vthread@std@@@2@@std@@A) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::condition_variable ThreadPool::_DoneWithWork" (?_DoneWithWork@ThreadPool@@0Vcondition_variable@std@@A) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const (* HyperCube::MarchingSquares::edges)[5]" (?edges@MarchingSquares@HyperCube@@2QAY04$$CBHA) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "char const * * type_names" (?type_names@@3PAPEBDA) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "char const * * BoundaryNames" (?BoundaryNames@@3PAPEBDA) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "char const * * ShowGlobalResidualNames" (?ShowGlobalResidualNames@@3PAPEBDA) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static unsigned int volatile ThreadPool::_RemainingTasks" (?_RemainingTasks@ThreadPool@@0IC) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static char const * const StackTracer::exec" (?exec@StackTracer@@2PEBDEB) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static char const * const ImageWriterParams::DefaultTileExtension" (?DefaultTileExtension@ImageWriterParams@@2PEBDEB) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static enum ThreadPool::ScheduleType ThreadPool::DefaultSchedule" (?DefaultSchedule@ThreadPool@@2W4ScheduleType@1@A) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
```

And more. Taking one example from the above list of errors `ThreadPool::DefaultSchedule` this is defined in one of the include files I reference and is part of my code base. This `struct` is defined as

```
struct ThreadPool
{
    enum ParallelType
    {
#ifdef _OPENMP
        OPEN_MP ,
#endif // _OPENMP
        THREAD_POOL ,
        ASYNC ,
        NONE
    };
    static const std::vector< std::string > ParallelNames;

    enum ScheduleType
    {
        STATIC ,
        DYNAMIC
    };
    static const std::vector< std::string > ScheduleNames;

    static size_t DefaultChunkSize;
    static ScheduleType DefaultSchedule;

    template< typename ... Functions >
    static void ParallelSections( const Functions & ... functions )
    {
        std::vector< std::future< void > > futures( sizeof...(Functions) );
        _ParallelSections( &futures[0] , functions ... );
        for( size_t t=0 ; t<futures.size() ; t++ ) futures[t].get();
    }

    static void Parallel_for( size_t begin , size_t end , const std::function< void ( unsigned int , size_t ) > &iterationFunction , ScheduleType schedule=DefaultSchedule , size_t chunkSize=DefaultChunkSize )
    {
        if( begin>=end ) return;
        size_t range = end - begin;
        size_t chunks = ( range + chunkSize - 1 ) / chunkSize;
        unsigned int threads = (unsigned int)NumThreads();
        std::atomic< size_t > index;
        index.store( 0 );


        if( range<chunkSize || _ParallelType==NONE || threads==1 )
        {
            for( size_t i=begin ; i<end ; i++ ) iterationFunction( 0 , i );
            return;
        }

        auto _ChunkFunction = [ &iterationFunction , begin , end , chunkSize ]( unsigned int thread , size_t chunk )
        {
            const size_t _begin = begin + chunkSize*chunk;
            const size_t _end = std::min< size_t >( end , _begin+chunkSize );
            for( size_t i=_begin ; i<_end ; i++ ) iterationFunction( thread , i );
        };
        auto _StaticThreadFunction = [ &_ChunkFunction , chunks , threads ]( unsigned int thread )
        {
            for( size_t chunk=thread ; chunk<chunks ; chunk+=threads ) _ChunkFunction( thread , chunk );
        };
        auto _DynamicThreadFunction = [ &_ChunkFunction , chunks , &index ]( unsigned int thread )
        {
            size_t chunk;
            while( ( chunk=index.fetch_add(1) )<chunks ) _ChunkFunction( thread , chunk );
        };

        if     ( schedule==STATIC  ) _ThreadFunction = _StaticThreadFunction;
        else if( schedule==DYNAMIC ) _ThreadFunction = _DynamicThreadFunction;

        if( false ){}
#ifdef _OPENMP
        else if( _ParallelType==OPEN_MP )
        {
            if( schedule==STATIC )
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads( threads ) schedule( static , 1 )
                for( int c=0 ; c<chunks ; c++ ) _ChunkFunction( omp_get_thread_num() , c );
            else if( schedule==DYNAMIC )
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads( threads ) schedule( dynamic , 1 )
                for( int c=0 ; c<chunks ; c++ ) _ChunkFunction( omp_get_thread_num() , c );
        }
#endif // _OPENMP
        else if( _ParallelType==ASYNC )
        {
            static std::vector< std::future< void > > futures;
            futures.resize( threads-1 );
            for( unsigned int t=1 ; t<threads ; t++ ) futures[t-1] = std::async( std::launch::async , _ThreadFunction , t );
            _ThreadFunction( 0 );
            for( unsigned int t=1 ; t<threads ; t++ ) futures[t-1].get();
        }
        else if( _ParallelType==THREAD_POOL )
        {
            unsigned int targetTasks = 0;
            if( !SetAtomic( &_RemainingTasks , threads-1 , targetTasks ) )
            {
                WARN( "nested for loop, reverting to serial" );
                for( size_t i=begin ; i<end ; i++ ) iterationFunction( 0 , i );
            }
            else
            {
                _WaitingForWorkOrClose.notify_all();
                {
                    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( _Mutex );
                    _DoneWithWork.wait( lock , [&]( void ){ return _RemainingTasks==0; } );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static unsigned int NumThreads( void ){ return (unsigned int)_Threads.size()+1; }

    static void Init( ParallelType parallelType , unsigned int numThreads=std::thread::hardware_concurrency() )
    {
        _ParallelType = parallelType;
        if( _Threads.size() && !_Close )
        {
            _Close = true;
            _WaitingForWorkOrClose.notify_all();
            for( unsigned int t=0 ; t<_Threads.size() ; t++ ) _Threads[t].join();
        }
        _Close = true;
        numThreads--;
        _Threads.resize( numThreads );
        if( _ParallelType==THREAD_POOL )
        {
            _RemainingTasks = 0;
            _Close = false;
            for( unsigned int t=0 ; t<numThreads ; t++ ) _Threads[t] = std::thread( _ThreadInitFunction , t );
        }
    }
    static void Terminate( void )
    {
        if( _Threads.size() && !_Close )
        {
            _Close = true;
            _WaitingForWorkOrClose.notify_all();
            for( unsigned int t=0 ; t<_Threads.size() ; t++ ) _Threads[t].join();
            _Threads.resize( 0 );
        }
    }
private:
    ThreadPool( const ThreadPool & ){}
    ThreadPool &operator = ( const ThreadPool & ){ return *this; }

    template< typename Function >
    static void _ParallelSections( std::future< void > *futures , const Function &function ){ *futures = std::async( std::launch::async , function ); }
    template< typename Function , typename ... Functions >
    static void _ParallelSections( std::future< void > *futures , const Function &function , const Functions& ... functions )
    {
        *futures = std::async( std::launch::async , function );
        _ParallelSections( futures+1 , functions ... );
    }
    static void _ThreadInitFunction( unsigned int thread )
    {
        // Wait for the first job to come in
        std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock( _Mutex );
        _WaitingForWorkOrClose.wait( lock );
        while( !_Close )
        {
            lock.unlock();
            // do the job
            _ThreadFunction( thread );

            // Notify and wait for the next job
            lock.lock();
            _RemainingTasks--;
            if( !_RemainingTasks ) _DoneWithWork.notify_all();
            _WaitingForWorkOrClose.wait( lock );
        }
    }

    static bool _Close;
    static volatile unsigned int _RemainingTasks;
    static std::mutex _Mutex;
    static std::condition_variable _WaitingForWorkOrClose , _DoneWithWork;
    static std::vector< std::thread > _Threads;
    static std::function< void ( unsigned int ) > _ThreadFunction;
    static ParallelType _ParallelType;
};
```

Clearly `static ScheduleType DefaultSchedule;` being a static variable is causing a problem and the other errors are likely to be caused by the same issues (this is not my code originally and I need to wrap it to expose to C#).

1. For the case of `ThreadPool` why is the value type `struct ThreadPool` that is a memeber of my `PossionSurfaceReconstructor` class causing this problem?
2. What is the easiest way around this (not changing the `struct` to `class` for each instance of the error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#include` directive essentially performs text-level copy and paste of the contents of the specified file at the point where the `#include` appears. Your header `MyMiscellany.h` contains definitions for a bunch of static member variables:

```cpp
size_t ThreadPool::DefaultChunkSize = 128;
ThreadPool::ScheduleType ThreadPool::DefaultSchedule = ThreadPool::DYNAMIC;
bool ThreadPool::_Close;
volatile unsigned int ThreadPool::_RemainingTasks;
std::mutex ThreadPool::_Mutex;
std::condition_variable ThreadPool::_WaitingForWorkOrClose;
std::condition_variable ThreadPool::_DoneWithWork;
std::vector< std::thread > ThreadPool::_Threads;
std::function< void ( unsigned int ) > ThreadPool::_ThreadFunction;
ThreadPool::ParallelType ThreadPool::_ParallelType;
```

The moment this header is included into more than one .cpp file, there will be more than one definition of these variables. There can be only one definition of a non-inline function or variable in a program [[basic.def.odr]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#4), which is exactly what the linker complains about:

> 2>wrappers.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static bool ThreadPool::_Close" (?_Close@ThreadPool@@0_NA) already defined in poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj
>   […]

This error message just tells you that `ThreadPool::_Close`, etc., for which there appears a definition in `wrappers.obj`, already had a definition in `poisson_surface_reconstructor.obj`. Both, `poisson_surface_reconstructor.cpp` as well as `wrappers.cpp` (indirectly) included `MyMiscellany.h`, thus, each of the two object files resulting from compiling these two .cpp files contains definitions for all these variables. The definitions were pasted into each .cpp file when they included `MyMiscellany.h`.

To solve this problem, you can either make the variables in question inline (requires C++17), in which case you can also keep the definition inside the class rather than having to define the variable outside of the class

```cpp
class ThreadPool
{
    …
    inline static bool Close = true;
    …
};
```

or move the definition to a separate .cpp file (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c) for more on that).

---

Note: `extern "C"` has got nothing to do with demangling anything. All it does is declare that the entity in question shall have C language linkage, whatever that means on the target platform. On Windows, for example, [even C linkage may still involve name mangling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=vs-2019#FormatC)…

Furthermore, I would suggest to replace your `volatile` variable `_RemainingTasks` and custom `SetAtomic` implementation with [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Finally, be aware that identifiers that contain a double underscore as well as identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter such as, e.g., `_Close`, are reserved [[lex.name]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.name#3). You are actually not allowed to use identifiers like that in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried to include the namespace-scope variables within the PossionSurfaceReconstructor, but I seem to hit the same errors. Are you suggesting that if I merely mark the cmdLineParameters and the cmdLineReadable variables as extern this should compile? I am currently away from my desk so cannot check this. I can make this code available and provide a bounty of your choosing if you can help me fix this problem. Thanks for taking the time to respond it iis most appreciated.

Comment: I have edited the question, I would very much appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: @MoonKnight I'm unfortunately quite busy at the moment, but it's on my todo list for later or maybe tomorrow to have a look… ;-)

Comment: @MoonKnight I've had a look at the code you uploaded and updated my question accordingly. Hope it's more clear now where the errors come from and what to do about it…