# How to use and access static pointer-to-member value s_ptm inside class?

Tags: c++, pointers, member

We can declare and use **instance-level pointer-to-member** value/func inside class.
And using `obj.*(obj.ptm)` or `ptr->*(ptr->ptm)` pattern to access.

But if declare them as **static type-level s_ptm** value/func, how to initialize and access/use them?

```
class C
{
  public:
     static int s_i;
     static int C::* s_ptm; //declare static ptm value OK here
};
```

Q: How to initialize and access s_ptm?

[coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44fa362afb8462ef](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44fa362afb8462ef)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c

Comment: `C` has no `int` member, so there is no way to use `s_ptm`

Comment: But we can declare s_ptm inside class C and `int C::* i =nullptr` to initialize it outside of class. Why `no way to use` it?

Comment: it points to a member of `C` of type `int`, but `C` has no member of type `int`

Comment: why non-static  `int C::* i` is ok? if C has no member of type int

Comment: it doesnt matter if it is static or not. If `C` has no `int` member then a pointer to a `int` member of `C` is of little use. What do you acutally want to achieve? What did you try and what error do you get?

Comment: Ok, I add `static int s_i` to class C. And use `int C::* i=& C::s_i;` to get `error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int C::*' with an rvalue of type 'int *'`

Comment: please include a [mcve] and the error message in the question.

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? Do you want to get a pointer to `C::s_i` ? Or do you want to initialize `s_ptm` ? Why do you need a pointer to member?

Comment: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44fa362afb8462ef check out here

Comment: why cant you include that together with the error message in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers to static members are just plain pointers. You cannot assign a pointer to a static member to a pointer to member. The good news is: You don't need it. Pointers to members enable you to point to a member and then given an instance you can access its member via that pointer. For a static member this isnt needed, because all instances share the same static member.

To initialize `s_ptm` you need an `int` member first:

```
struct C {
    static int s_i;
    static int C::* s_ptm; //declare static ptm value OK here
    int c;
};

int C::* C::s_ptm = &C::c;     // OK
//int C::* C::s_ptm = &C::s_i; // NOPE !
int* p = &C::s_i;              // OK
```

However, with only a single `int` member a pointer to member of type `int` is no that useful. Instead of accessing `C::c` via the pointer you can access it by its name. Pointers to members are useful when there is more than one member of the same type or in a generic context.

Comment: I know a static ptm point to a instance member is not that useful. But out of curiosity, what the result of de-ref of `C::s_ptm`? how to de-ref it? `*(C::s_ptm)` not work

Comment: @Larry what is the meaning of "not work" ? Works for me here: https://godbolt.org/z/8btrCF

Comment: Oops, I forgot `obj.*(C::s_ptm)` != `*(C::s_ptm)`