# How to define std::regex object as a const static member in a class and use it in a function?

Tags: c++, regex, static, member

I have a class

```
class C
{
  private:
    const static std::regex r;
}
```

and I want to give the variable r some string to parse, as example:

```
//ATTENTION: IT'S NOT CORRECT, HOW TO DEFINED IT CORRECTLY?
std::regex r("Hello\n");
```

and I have a function in the same class, where I have multiple if-statements to check if the string is parsed

```
if(std::regex_match(user_input,r)
{
  std::cout << "match";
}
else
{
  std::cout << "no match";
}
```

How can I use r correctly and compare user_input with r, when r has not been defined?

Comment: Just declare: const std::regex C::r("<pattern>");

Comment: @PedroBoechat where?

Comment: Just add the `C::` prefix to what you already have.

Comment: Usually the static members are defined in the classes implementation file (e.g.: C.cpp).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize private static members in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c)

Comment: the function is in the same class, I don't actually understand how to use regex in a function

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```cpp
// === header file c.h ===
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H
#include <regex>
class C
{
private:
   const static std::regex r;
};
#endif

// === source file c.cpp ===
#include "c.h"
const std::regex C::r{"Hello\n"};
```

Comment: why is it only const and not const static?

Comment: Because there is only "one" instance of `r` for static members so the `static` keyword used in the class will not mean the same thing when defining the varaible in the cpp-file. There it would only mean to hide it from other translation units.