# c++ the static func cant use variable

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
static map<int,int> aaa;
static bool cmp(int a,int b) {
    if(aaa[a]==aaa[b])
        return a>b;
    return aaa[a]<aaa[b];
}
vector<int> frequencySort(vector<int>& nums) {
    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
        aaa[nums[i]]++;
    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),cmp);
    return nums;
}
};
```

i dont know whats wrong. its looks like have no problem.the map:aaa cant be used int the function cmp.
the debug is:

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: Solution::aaa

clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: the code cant be complie in leetcode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize private static members in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c)